# how to write plugin that change the color scheme for control panel theme?

Tags: java, css, liferay, velocity, liferay-theme

after setting a theme as main theme for Control Panel (control panel->configuration->portal settings->display settings->look and feel), there is no option to select any of my color schemes that come with the theme,

how can i write plugin to make it possible to choose a color scheme?

Comment: You will have to write a _hook_ that changes the corresponding JSP page `/html/portlet/portal_settings/display_settings.jsp`.

Comment: thanks i know this is the page but what should i write to get this done :)

Comment: _How can I write a plugin_ indicates that _you_ would like to do it, not that you would like _us_ to do it. You can look at the file `/html/portlet/layouts_admin/look_and_feel_themes.jsp` how Liferay is doing it for the other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys i was able to solve this by adding JavaScript Code (`JQuery`), in the `main.js` file of the theme that execute on page load and detect the `Control panel` and change the class of `<body>` to the Color defined in the `main.js`.

Answer (score -1):

One of the approach to solve this scenario would be using **`Theme Setting API of Liferay`**.

You can provide color options in **`liferay-look-and-feel.xml`** of corresponding theme and `read this value in vm templates` and apply color to appropriate HTML element via `portal_normal.vm`

Here are few links for your reference :

- https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/designing-a-look-and-feel-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-09-en
- https://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/theme-settings-and-new-advanced-controls
- http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/settin-4

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but that's liferay theme settings what im asking for is to use a pre made color schemes for control panel it self theme.